# Connect to Oracle DB on Windows Server 2012, running on VMWare, remotely

Tags: oracle, vmware, windows-server-2012

I'm currently running Windows Server 2012 and Oracle Database 12c Enterprise in VMWare Player.

I need to connect to the aforementioned database externally, for example using my host OS to run scripts without developing on the VM itself. How do I go about it?

Any and all help will be appreciated; Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who stumbles here; the fix was simple.

**Step 1**: Make sure you have `lsnrctl` running.

**Step 2**: Find your VM's IP address using `ipconfig`.

**Step 3**: Use the connection string to access your Oracle DB:

`username/password@ip_addr:1521/db_name`

1521 can be changed to whatever port you're using.